# Inclusion of a subvariety is a cofibration

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I am interested in what generality the statement

 "*Inclusion of a subvariety X of an algebraic variety Y over $\mathbb{C}$ is a cofibration*" (*) 
 is true.

I have seen (stated without explanation) that it holds when $X$ is a closed subvariety and $Y$ is projective.

However, I am wondering whether (*) is true when $X$ is a projective and $Y$ is a smooth quasi-projective variety?

*Remarks:*

1. Here I refer to the analytic topology (so no Zariski).
2. There are many equivalent definitions for a map to be cofibration, and one of which works for an inclusion is a homotopy extension property:
   Inclusion
   $X\hookrightarrow Y $ is a cofibration iff any continuous map $Y \times {0} \cup X \times [0,1] \rightarrow Z$ can be extended to a continuous map
   $ Y \times [0,1] \rightarrow Z.$

Comment: Which topology do you mean? Zariski or Euclidean? Secondly, where did you come across this statement?

Comment: Also, what is meant by cofibration?

Comment: @BrianShin [Cofibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofibration) is the dual of fibration.

Comment: I explained which topology and definition of cofibration in remarks now.

Comment: And @KReiser, I gave a comment about when it is known to be true (see new version of question). The reason I care is because there is a standard statement saying: when an inclusion $X\rightarrow Y$ of topological spaces is a homotopy equivalence and a cofibration then $X$ is a deformational retract of $Y$

Comment: For Hausdorff spaces (which describes any projective or quasi-projective variety with the analytic topology), every cofibration must be a closed embedding. This is classical enough that I don't have a reference off-hand.

Comment: Yes that is true indeed. And in the case that I care in particular (X proj, Y qproj), the closed embedding condition is satisfied, so no contradictions.

Comment: Well, we can choose CW-pair structure for $(Y,X)$ (since $Y$ can be triangulated, and $X$ is contained in the intersection of finitely many hypersurfaces so throw those hypersurfaces in and refine), and so inclusion of $X$ in $Y$ is a cofibration.

Comment: Let me add that one can turn the category of varieties (with Zariski topology) into a variation of a Waldhausen category, i.e. a category with weak equivalences and cofibrations. There one takes exactly the inclusions of closed subvarieties to be the cofibrations. While this does not answer your question, it might still be of interest to you.

Comment: @user10354138 Why not an official answer?

Comment: @PaulFrost Because I don't want to spend time typing up the details of constructing a Whitney stratification.

Comment: @user10354138 yes I was wondering exactly whether (Y,X) can be made to be a CW pair. With these things I am usually worried about the non-compactness, hence Y being a non-finite CW complex. Is that not an issue in your argument?

Comment: No, it won't be.  In fact I don't need those finitely many hypersurfaces.  $X$ is compact means it is contained in a finite sub-CW-complex of $Y$ so I only need to refine those using a CW structure on $X$, which is easy enough.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks!